# How to automatically increase an Id field

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How can I auto increase an Id field automatically at the time of inserting the record in oracle11g.

P.S. - I don't want to use sequence or trigger.

Comment: Why do you want to build something that's already built, triggers and sequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a code/description table:

```
insert into TABLE (X_ID, X_DESC)  
(select max(b.X_ID) + 1, 'TEST DESC' from TABLE b);
```

But what's wrong with a sequence?  That's what it's for.

Comment: but this Query will require a dummy max value in the table we need to start with...

But I want to start it from the first record (no dummy record already present in table)...

Comment: @Shobhit Varshney nvl(max(b.X_ID), 0) + 1 But what about parallel inserts?

Comment: The question is asking for trouble, and this SQL will provide it. User1 inserts a row, then User2 inserts a row, then User1 commits, then User2 commits. Now you have either a duplicate ID, or a transaction that failed due to unique key violation. Sequences exist precisely to avoid this kind of situation.